# How to pass data from one activity to another activity by using intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

Here i wrote a code to pass data from one activity to another activity by using intents.. Please let me know if i need to do any corrections over here in my code.

```
   OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        nextIntent.putExtra("firstname", "Siva");
        nextIntent.putExtra("Secondname", "Kumar");
        startActivity(nextIntent);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SignIn Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Second Activity:

```
OnClickListener backListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent backIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundleData = receivedIntent.getExtras();
        bundleData.getString("firstname");
        bundleData.getString("secondname");
        startActivity(backIntent);
    }
};
```

Comment: Make correction for your "Secondname" in your Second Activity.

Comment: Is there a specific problem?

Comment: @laalto I am not getting output in the emulator

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this

1. pass data to SecondActivity

   ```
   Intent nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
   nextIntent.putExtra("firstname", "Siva");
   nextIntent.putExtra("Secondname", "Kumar");
   startActivity(nextIntent);
   ```
2. get data inside SecondActivity

   ```
   Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
   String firstname=receivedIntent.getStringExtra("firstname");
   String secondname=receivedIntent.getStringExtra("Secondname");
   ```

**EDIT**

SecondActivity.jaja

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    String firstname=receivedIntent.getStringExtra("firstname");
    String secondname=receivedIntent.getStringExtra("Secondname");

    TextView txtFirst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    txtFirst.setText(firstname);
    TextView txtSecond=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
    txtSecond.setText(secondname);
    Button back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();


        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Not working. Please look in to this once again.

Comment: It is working but I am not able to see the passed values in the second Activity.

Comment: display using Log or toast `Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, firstname,Toast.LENTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Dear Ketan, I already did that by using Toast and i am successful on that. I want to display as a text on the second activity.

Comment: It means you are getting value in SecondActivity..right ?

Comment: I am getting redirected to second activity. But not able to display the text.

Comment: post your secondactivity code

Comment: 'OnClickListener backListener = new OnClickListener() {
  
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   
   Intent backIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
   Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
   Bundle bundleData = receivedIntent.getExtras();
   bundleData.getString("firstname");
   bundleData.getString("secondname");
   startActivity(backIntent);
  }
 };'

Comment: why are you getting value in clicklistener. get value in oncreate method and display.

Comment: Then How can i go back to my first activity..?? Please Don't mind i am just a beginner. I need your help...

Comment: whenever you want to go back just call `finish()` method.

Comment: Please post the code of your version

Comment: try updated answer and make required changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use some String variables like below,

```
OnClickListener backListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent backIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
        String firstName = getIntent().getStringExtra("firstname");
        String secondName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Secondname");
        startActivity(backIntent);
    }
};
```

Now your two String variables firstName and secondName contains the information you required.

Comment: Sorry it's not worked... Please suggest me in your own coding style for simple data passing using intents... Thanks

Comment: @user3164399, I have updated my answer, please check it now. In "Secondname". your "S" is capital and in receiving part it is small. change it and check it again.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested... It is working but I am not able to see the passed values in the second intent.

Comment: @user3164399, sorry there was spelling mistake in secondname, I have updated it, please try again.

Comment: Still facing the same... Is there any other reason other than code..???

Comment: sure, can you upload your code in the question ?